# 2D Array angularjs to c#

Tags: c#, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I am able to call a c# method from an angular controllers as such:

angualarjs:

```
      $http.post('myC#Function', { "input": input )
        .success(function (response) {
            console.log("success send response: " + response);
        })
        .error(function (response) {
            console("error send response: " + response);
        });
```

C#

```
         public string myC#Function(string input)
    {
       return "success";
    }
```

My issues arises when i try to pass a 2D array from the angular to c# controller as such:

angularjs:

```
     var my2DArray= [[], []];
     // array is populated here (not shown)
      $http.post('myC#Function', { "inputArray": my2DArray)
        .success(function (response) {
            console.log("success send response: " + response);
        })
        .error(function (response) {
            console("error send response: " + response);
        });
```

c#

```
       public string myC#Function(string[,]input)
{
   return "success";
}
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Newtonsoft Json library (must already be in your project).

```
public string YourCSharpFunction(string yourJson2DArrayFromAngular)
{
     var your2DArrayInCSharp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[,]>(yourJson2DArrayFromAngular);
     return "success";
}
```

Comment: im getting the same error as the other answer. I'm receiving a NullReferenceException error when i try to return input[0][0] from c#, even though it's populated. any idea's?

Comment: What do you have in your2DArrayInCSharp in debug mode ? Is it correct ?

Answer (score 0):

send data using `JSON.stringify`

```
$http.post('myC#Function', { JSON.stringify({ input : input }) })
```

and C# function signature as

```
public string myC#Function(string[][] input) {}
```

You should add `contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"` into `post header`

Comment: I'm receiving a NullReferenceException error when i try to return input[0][0] from c#, even though it's populated. any idea's?

Comment: where are you getting this exception? I mean that line of code